# Getting a NPE when running an individual JUnit Test case on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I got multiple test cases that I set up as part of my project. Everything works well when I run the test entire test. However, when I try running a single method test case, it throws an exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.SubForestFilter.shouldRun(SubForestFilter.java:81)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.filter(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:110)
    at org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter.apply(Filter.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createFilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I'm using Java 1.8, Maven and Eclipse Mars release.

Any ideas as to whats causing this?

TIA

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=479730

Comment: I just upgraded my junit to use 4.6 version and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: @AlvinReyes you can provide your own answer and then accept it if you like.

Comment: @ScottNewson will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this bug

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=479730

Theres a pending issue on JUnit 4.4 support which is what i was using. Upgrading to 4.5 and above (in my case 4.6) resolved this issue on my end.

Thank you.

Comment: Just a question. Junit 4.12 is available in m2 central from Dec/2014. Any particluar reaspon why you are using 4.6 ?

Comment: No particular reason. This is for a greenfield (new source and everything) and figured we can use the new versions of JUnit libraries.